# Get filename and length from blob stream

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket, blob

I am using websockets to send a file from my c# server to my browser. I added the file name and filebytelength along with the file in the bytestream.

My c# code to include file name in the byte stream

```
string filename = "@\C:\Users\Username\Downloads\RAW1MB data.txt";
string shortName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName);
            byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(shortName);
            byte[] fileNamelen = BitConverter.GetBytes(shortName.Length);

            byte[] filedata = File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);

            byte[] senddata = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + filedata.Length];

            fileNamelen.CopyTo(senddata, 0);
            fileNameByte.CopyTo(senddata, 4);
            filedata.CopyTo(senddata, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
            await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(senddata,0,senddata.Length),WebSocketMessageType.Binary,true,CancellationToken.None );
```

This is my Javascript included in my HTML

```
websocket.onmessage = function (e) {

        if(e.data instanceof Blob){
            window.alert("Getting file");
            
            var filedata = e.data;
            var filenameLen = filedata.slice(0,4);
            Console.log(filenamelen);// I am getting Blob{ size: 4 ,type: ""}

}
        else{
        writeToScreen("<span>RESPONSE: " + e.data + "</span>");
        }
    };
```

From the `console.log` I am getting  `Blob{ size:4,type :""}`.
How do I get the integer and string from first 4 bytes and the following respectively?
So without getting the `filenamelen` I am unable to get the `filename` as well.